# Which Star Trek: TNG episodes are sampled in the song "Data & Picard" from artist Pogo?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, music

The musician Pogo has a new song called "**[Data & Picard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bl5TUw7sUBs)**" ([spotify link](http://spotify:track:5VcOZYRlC02MDPD95bi0rs)) on the album "**[Weightless](https://pogomix.bandcamp.com/album/weightless)**". ([spotify link](http://spotify:album:2Hog1V8mdTWKhCYqI5paph))

Pogo is famous for sampling elements of movies, tv, music to create his tracks.

I recognize several of the samples he used from **Star Trek: The Next Generation** but am interested if all the samples and correlating them to the episodes they came from can be identified?

Here is a YouTube video of the track:

Comment: +1 even though the vid was weird and somewhat creepy while also being morbidly quite funny.

Comment: Disappointed Darmok and Jilad at Tenagra wasn't in the song.

Comment: thank you for asking this, I'd run across the video yesterday and couldn't sleep last night I was so freaked out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From one listen through:

1. When I was in the academy... Cheer up my lads. [Allegiance:](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Allegiance_(episode))
   Picard confuses ten forward by singing.
2. Is better to have loved and lost than never to have loved at all...
   [Menage a Trois:](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_%C3%A0_Troi_(episode)) Picard is quoting Shakespeare to [intimidate
   a Ferengi who wanted to marry Lwaxana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45VAelC_QsI).
3. Really quite hypnotic... [Timescape:](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Timescape_(episode)) Picard is doing an
   impression of a lecturer.
4. Tea, Earl Grey, Hot [Contagion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Contagion_(episode)): This could be from one of
   several episodes.
5. Jean Luc Picard of the Federation Starship... Again, this could be
   from almost any episode.
6. That's an interesting twist. [The Hunted](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Hunted_(episode))

Comment: [Quite hypnotic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSiBvYodew8).

Comment: To add to ench's answer, the long string of numbers is from "Brothers" (http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Brothers_(episode)) when Data recites the lockout override codes to usurp control of the Enterprise.

Comment: I really feel this answer could use a little more work/contribution.    Someone should be able to identify the exact episode for #5.  Plus as @Vanguard3000 points out, the answer isn't complete.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to ench's answer, Pogo's [description of his video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/bl5TUw7sUBs) describes a couple more dialogue sources:

> The track opens with the Klingon Victory Song [no episode cited], followed by a remix of Data singing Che Gelida Manina [from *La Bohème*] in the episode [*In Theory*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/In%20Theory%20(episode)). This episode was the first ever to be directed by Patrick Stewart and I didn't realize this until after the track was finished.

Comment: Thank you for this, it was driving me crazy...

Comment: Thank you. Here is a clip of that scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_6raHHDLEA